# Algorithm / algorithmicx horizontal lines in booktabs style

Tags: algorithms, booktabs, algorithmicx

I am using packages [algorithm](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithms/algorithms.pdf), [algorithmicx](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf) and [booktabs](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf).

There are horizontal lines for both algorithms and tables. As you can see, the lines have different line strength and spacing.

I would like the horizontal lines and the spacing surrounding the algorithm and its caption to match exactly the beautiful design from `booktabs`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
\State $r\gets a\bmod b$
\While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
\State $a\gets b$
\State $b\gets r$
\State $r\gets a\bmod b$
\EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
\State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
First name & Last Name & Age \\
\midrule
John & Doe & 30 \\
John & Doe & 30 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Member for more than two years, seven questions, and no MWE:  -1

Comment: Well, good luck with that but what is exactly your question?

Comment: I updated the question, sorry for the missing information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nice idea!

We can create a new float style by modifying `ruled`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\fs@booktabsruled{%
  \def\@fs@cfont{\bfseries\strut}\let\@fs@capt\floatc@ruled
  \def\@fs@pre{\hrule height\heavyrulewidth depth0pt \kern\belowrulesep}%
  \def\@fs@mid{\kern\aboverulesep\hrule height\lightrulewidth\kern\belowrulesep}%
  \def\@fs@post{\kern\aboverulesep\hrule height\heavyrulewidth\relax}%
  \let\@fs@iftopcapt\iftrue
}
\makeatother

\floatstyle{booktabsruled}
\restylefloat{algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
\State $r\gets a\bmod b$
\While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
\State $a\gets b$
\State $b\gets r$
\State $r\gets a\bmod b$
\EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
\State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
First name & Last Name & Age \\
\midrule
John & Doe & 30 \\
John & Doe & 30 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was getting some interaction between `captionsetup`, some other bits of my preamble (couldn't quite pin down exactly what), and this solution. This interaction resulted in the algorithm's caption being centered (which was undesired). If anyone else has this problem, I found that setting `\captionsetup[algorithm]{singlelinecheck=off}` fixed it.