# algorithm2e with booktabs style and listing the algorithms in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, algorithm2e, booktabs, newfloat

I'm using the solution that @egreg provided on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/345745/127473), but I'm using the [`algorithm2e`](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf) package instead of [`algorithms`](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/algorithms/algorithms.pdf).

I'd like to retain the design from [`booktabs`](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) but the command `\listofalgorithms` prints an empty list.

I think this is due to the fact that now the algorithms are figures, so the `.loa` file results to be empty.
I don't know how to proceed, any suggestion is appreciated.

This is my not working MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}

# https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/345745/127473
\makeatletter
\newcommand\fs@booktabsruled{%
  \def\@fs@cfont{\bfseries\strut}\let\@fs@capt\floatc@ruled
  \def\@fs@pre{\hrule height\heavyrulewidth depth0pt \kern\belowrulesep}%
  \def\@fs@mid{\kern\aboverulesep\hrule height\lightrulewidth\kern\belowrulesep}%
  \def\@fs@post{\kern\aboverulesep\hrule height\heavyrulewidth\relax}%
  \let\@fs@iftopcapt\iftrue
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{algorithm}{h}{alg}

\floatstyle{booktabsruled}
\restylefloat{algorithm}

\begin{document}

\listofalgorithms % empty

\begin{algorithm} 
    \caption{test}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

And this is the result
[image: mwe]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macros `\@fs@pre`, `\@fs@mid`, and `\@fs@post` from the post you linked have `algorithm2e` counterparts called `\@algocf@pre@ruled`, `\algocf@caption@ruled`, `\@algocf@post@ruled`, so just use egreg's definitions for them. Algorithms from `algorithm2e` are already floating and the package already takes care of the corresponding list-of.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% Values shamelessly taken from egreg's answer in 
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/345745/82917
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@algocf@pre@ruled}{\hrule height\heavyrulewidth depth0pt \kern\belowrulesep}
\renewcommand*{\algocf@caption@ruled}{\box\algocf@capbox\kern\aboverulesep\hrule height\lightrulewidth\kern\belowrulesep}
\renewcommand*{\@algocf@post@ruled}{\kern\aboverulesep\hrule height\heavyrulewidth\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listofalgorithms

\begin{algorithm} 
 \While{condition}{
  something;
 }
\caption{Some nice algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

(Huge screenshot, otherwise the rendering of the different rule thicknesses was bad.)

[image]